# Select debug browser in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, microsoft, visual-studio-2022

- There used to be an option to select the browser you wanted to debug in.
- There "play" debug button also used to be available on debug toolbar.

Are there settings to get this functionality back or are they just **gone** now?

---

**Visual Studio 2022**

[image: Visual Studio 2022 Debug toolbar]

[image: Visual Studio 2022 Debug menu]

---

**Visual Studio 2019**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the tiny dropdown arrow at the end of each toolbar allows you to add/remove missing buttons.

But I am still not sure how to select the debugging browser.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have 'ASP.NET and web development' workload installed.